# Changing Label Text on client side are not accessible on server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have below header label

```
Billed Amount:
<label >$</label>
<asp:Label ID="billed"  runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
```

Also i have child repeater with text input like below

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt" >
     <HeaderTemplate>
         ....
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtB" onchange="AmountChanged(this)" Text='<%# Bind("Billed") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
     </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

In AmountChanged JavaScript function i have written to sum all the repeater item billed amount and change value on header

But when i am getting label value its coming as previous value only. JavaScript changes are not working on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to add a ***HiddenField***. Whenever you assign a value to `billed` label, you also assign it to `BilledHiddenField` HiddenField.

Then you can read `BilledHiddenField.Value` at server side instead of `billed.Text`.

```
<asp:Label ID="billed"  runat="server" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
<asp:HiddenField id="BilledHiddenField" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Labels won't be persisted on postback. A good way to solve this would be recalculating the total on load:

We could add some `data-` attributes so we can easily id the elements

```
<asp:Label data-billed="" runat="server" ID="billed"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtB" data-amount="" Text='<%# Eval("Billed") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

And then you calculate the total on load:

```
var amount = 0;

$("[data-amount]").each(function (index, el) {
    if ($(el).val()) {
        amount += parseInt($(el).val(), 10);
    }
});

$("[data-billed]").text(amount);
```